# How to write pandas dataframe to a csv with varying row length

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

I've read in a csv in Pandas that has a variance in row values and some blank lines in between the rows.

Example:
[image: Sample data]

```
This is an example

CustomerID; 123;
Test ID; 144;
Seen_on_Tv; yes;

now_some_measurements_1;
test1; 333; 444; 555; 
test2; 344; 455; 566;
test3; 5544; 3424; 5456;

comment; this test sample is only for this Stackoverflow question, but
similar to my real data.
```

When reading in this file, I use this code:

```
pat = pd.read_csv(FileName, skip_blank_lines = False, header=None, sep=";", names=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']) 
pat.head(10)
```

output:

```
                         a      b       c       d    e
0       This is an example    NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
1                      NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
2               CustomerID    123     NaN     NaN  NaN
3                  Test ID    144     NaN     NaN  NaN
4               Seen_on_Tv    yes     NaN     NaN  NaN
5                      NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
6  now_some_measurements_1    NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN
7                    test1    333   444.0   555.0     
8                    test2    344   455.0   566.0  NaN
9                    test3   5544  3424.0  5456.0  NaN
```

This works, especially since I have to change the CustomerID (via this code example) etc:

```
newID = 'HASHED'
pat.loc[pat['a'] == 'CustomerID', 'b']=newID
```

However, when I save this changed dataframe to csv, I get a lot of 'trailing' seperators (";") as most of the columns are empty and especially with the blank lines.

```
pat.to_csv('out.csv', sep=";", index = False, header=False)
```

output (out.csv):

```
This is an example;;;;
;;;;
CustomerID; HASHED;;;
Test ID; 144;;;
Seen_on_Tv; yes;;;
;;;;
now_some_measurements_1;;;;
test1; 333;444.0;555.0; 
test2; 344;455.0;566.0;
test3; 5544;3424.0;5456.0;
;;;;
comment; this test sample is only for this Stackoverflow question, but similar to my real
data. 
;;;
```

I've searched almost everywhere for a solution, but can not find it.
How to write only the column values to the csv file that are not blank (except for the blank lines to separate the sections, which need to remain blank of course)?

Thank you in advance for your kind help.

Comment: You realise that by doing that you'll make it an invalid delimiter separated file and it may not load back in to some systems... (for instance... you couldn't reload your output back into pandas...)

Comment: Hi Jon, thank you for your question and I do understand. This is however a specific request from one of my clients, who have build up a tool to specifically read these files with the current set-up and that tool could not work with the separators that I've added in the export (the additional ";")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to just parse your `out.csv` and for the non-blank lines (those consisting solely of `;`'s) - write a stripped version of that line, eg:

```
with open('out.csv') as fin, open('out2.csv', 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        if stripped := line.strip(';\n '):
            fout.write(stripped + '\n')
        else:
            fout.write(line)
```

Will give you:

```
This is an example
;;;;
CustomerID; HASHED
Test ID; 144
Seen_on_Tv; yes
;;;;
now_some_measurements_1
test1; 333;444.0;555.0
test2; 344;455.0;566.0
test3; 5544;3424.0;5456.0
;;;;
comment; this test sample is only for this Stackoverflow question, but similar to my real
data.
;;;
```

You could also pass a `io.StringIO` object to `to_csv` (to save writing to disk and then re-reading) as the output destination, then parse that in a similar fashion to produce your desired output file.

Comment: Thank you for this prompt and great solution, it worked on my test file and on a real file. I've added an additional line to empty the 'blank-rows' as well. Again thank you.